# White lines on [searchDisplayController setActive] and "No results" when beginning typing

Tags: iphone

With help of this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I wanted to show the keyboard in a search when the view loads. It works just fine, but it looks quite ugly (why the white lines in there?):

[search table with white lines http://img42.yfrog.com/img42/7503/latest1.png](http://img42.yfrog.com/img42/7503/latest1.png)

When I begin to write and remove all the letters it looks like it should from the beginning:

[search table withour white lines http://img3.yfrog.com/img3/6176/testpn.png](http://img3.yfrog.com/img3/6176/testpn.png)

How do I fix this?

And i have another problem. When I begin to type something it instantly shows "No results" even before one presses the "Search" button, how can I change this behaviour?

[search table with 'nothing found' http://img245.yfrog.com/img245/4366/bildschirmfoto20091014ui.png](http://img245.yfrog.com/img245/4366/bildschirmfoto20091014ui.png)

Comment: I'll ask about that on the iPhone Tech Talks in Hamburg, hopfully thy can explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "no results" is still a problem. I found at a apple support forum that it is not implemented this way. So I was looking for workarounds. The first thing you want to do is:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    if([searchString length] < 1) [items removeAllObjects];
    if ([items count] < 1) {
        [controller.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
        [controller.searchResultsTableView setRowHeight:800];       
    }
    return YES;
}
```

That way you get just one big table cell which looks gray and translucent. When you reloaded the searchTableView then you want to change this changes back:

```
- (void)gotDataReload {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setRowHeight:44];
}
```

Hope this helps the next one who has this problems.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue seems to be somehow related to timing. I got it work with this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(toTheSearchbar) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)toTheSearchbar {
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Even a delay of 0 works fine, without it I get the white lines.